# what is "function(response){}"

Tags: javascript, callback

I was reading the Facebook API when I come across [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.5), where there is this snippet:

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  caption: 'An example caption',
}, function(response){});
```

This code confuses me. If my understanding is correct, this is a function call of `FB.ui`, its first parameter is an object literal. But what is its 2nd parameter, what is this `function(response){}`? It seems to me this should be a syntax error.

Comment: That is an anonymous function that does nothing, it should bot raise syntax error, it is valid synatx

Answer (score 4):

This is a callback. Because JS operates in the browser, it can't simply sit and wait for a network request to complete. The browser has to go off and do other work while the server is sending a response, so callbacks are used to call back into the code once some remote operation has finished.

This particular pattern, of:

```
remoteCall(objectParams, responseCallback)
```

is a very common way to handle some request that goes out to a server or filesystem. It's a way of putting the actual IO operation in a separate thread, so as not to freeze the rest of the program.

There are three main ways to handle asynchronous operations in JS:

#### Callback Parameters

You can pass these as function parameters or part of the object:

```
remoteCall(objectParams, responseCallback)
remoteCall({
  success: responseCallback
})
```

The function is responsible for invoking the functions you provide once it has reached some state (finished, failed, progress changed).

#### Events

A more elegant, but somewhat more complex, way of handling this is through proper events. The built-in XHR class uses these (from [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
    if (this.readyState === DONE){
        alert(this.readyState);
    }
};
```

In this model, you subscribe to a named event, which will be called at some future time.

The DOM (web page hosting a script) typically interacts with the script via events, using standardized names. MDN has a page of [the DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events), what info they use, and when they're fired.

#### Promise(/Deferred)

This is a newer model combining callbacks and events. jQuery is well-known for using a [mutilated version of promises](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/), but with real promises, a request can become:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Stuff worked!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
});
```

[This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) (where the above snippet comes from) has a fantastic comparison of events and promises.

One of the best implementations of promises is Bluebird, which has [fantastic documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) on the patterns and how they work.

#### What You're Seeing

An anonymous function (declared inline, with no name) is used to pass a function around as an object (because functions in JS are objects). If a function is named:

```
function foo() { ... }
// do some things
foo(); // do foo
```

then you are able to call it from within the same scope. If a function is not named:

```
var foo = function() { ... }
// do some things
foo(); // do foo
```

then you need a *reference* in order to call it. The name is not published for just anybody to use.

This is the basis of immediately-invoking functions, which can be used to do some logic when a script is loaded:

```
(function () {
    ...
}());
```

This function calls itself once when it loads, but has no name (and is not assigned to a variable), preventing it from being called again.